# Impact of releasing a variable more then the retain count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a instance variable declared as a retain property & then I released it 2 times. After releasing it I am not using it. This is not resulting into any crash. Is there any other impact of releasing a variable more than required (given that the variable is not going to be used after the release):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myVariable;
self.myVariable = nil;
self.myVariable = nil;
```

Comment: You appear to be confused about the difference between an object and a variable.  A variable can be released an infinite number of times if it is nil.  Whereas releasing a non-nil object just one too any times will cause a crash.

Comment: I think you are right. Can you put this as an answer so that I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be confused about the difference between a variable and an object.  A single variable can be used with a release an infinite number of times (say, if is nil, or it holds a completely different retained object before each release, etc. This is because a variable can hold no object, or different objects at different times.).  In your example, the variable holds no object (nil) during your second release.

But releasing any one non-nil object just one time too many can be the cause of a crash.

Answer (score 4):

You are not, in fact, releasing it twice. This is because you're using properties. The first time you call `self.myVariable = nil`, you're releasing it (assuming it had a value). But the second time, *it's already nil*, so there's nothing to release.

In general, actually releasing an object multiple times (or more accurately, having more releases than retains) is really bad and will almost certainly crash your app.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually releasing it twice. Given that the setter looks something like this:

```
- (void)setMyVariable:(NSString)value
{
    [myVariable release];
    myVariable = [value retain];
}
```

The first `self.myVariable = nil` will release the `myVariable` iVar, and will also set it to nil. The next `self.myVariable = nil` will do nothing, because `[nil release]` does nothing.

Actually overreleasing an object will (usually) cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen in your code. I assume you are using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) so you are "releasing" it by setting its pointer to nil.

How it really works is, suppose you have a NSString object allocated in memory, you create it and you assign a pointer to it.

So now your pointer is pointing to that object, what arc does is: If an object no longer has a pointer pointing to it then it is automatically released. Assuming you had ONLY that "myvariable" pointer on that NSString then it will be released the moment you set it to nil.

If you set the myvariable to nil again then you are absolutely not doing anything to it since the object was already released before.

Note that this means that if you have ANOTHER variable also pointing to that NSString then the object WONT be released but myvariable wont be pointing to it anymore.

I forgot to mention, you can find an excellent explanation about how arc works in "iOS 5 by tutorials" by Ray Wenderlich.

PD: If you are using ARC u should change your

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myVariable;

to

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myVariable;

Answer (score 0):

With the new ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) in iOS 5 you shouldn't worry about this issue, since the compiler takes care of this.

Learn more about it here:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

However, if you can't / don't want to use ARC, here is my alternative answer:

By accessing your vars the way you are doing ( `self.var = nil` ), my guess is that these synthesized functions take care of not releasing a non-retained var, so you are safe to do so as many times you like (not very elegant though).

If, on the other hand, you would explicitly call release like this `[var release]` twice or more, you might run into pretty nasty problems.